# Data validation to get error message (input in cell doesn't equal name in a list)

Tags: excel, vba, validation, excel-formula

I have looked at some examples for my question but couldn't find an answer that works.

**Background:**
I have a list of items (let's say apple, orange, banana) in Sheet1 (A2:A77, which is already a defined range with the name "Liste").
I then have on another sheet (Let's say Sheet2) with several cells where a userform (created with vba code) pops up where the user can choose an item and click OK.

However, due to the nature of the userform (and the list), you can have spelling errors etc and it will still be accepted. So I would like to create a check where it matches the input to the given list (to prevent users from putting anything else in). The userform/code is on purpose to keep it searchable (rather than just a simple data validation list).

**Issue:**
I tried to create this with vba code that checks the input, matches it to the Sheet1 list and if there is no match, shows a msgbox with a statement. This partially worked (for some letters but not others, very strange).

Here is the code I had:

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.EnableEvents = False
Dim rSearchRng As Range
Dim vFindvar As Variant

If Not Intersect([B7:B26], Target) Is Nothing Then
    Set rSearchRng = Sheet4.Range("Liste")
    Set vFindvar = rSearchRng.Find(Target.Value)
    If Not vFindvar Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The Audit Project Name you have entered is not valid. Please try again!", vbExclamation, "Error!"
        Selection.ClearContents
    End If
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

So I was thinking of creating this error message instead with a simple data validation.

**Data validation**

- I have tried the "list" option (and put it equal to the named range) but that did nothing (no error box showed up)
- I have tried "Custom" with the following formula 'SUMPRODUCT(--(B12=Liste)>0)=TRUE (I found this on a post which worked for others when I tried it in the cell it gave me the expected "TRUE/FALSE" results) but still nothing shows up

**UPDATE**

Tigeravatars data validation recommendations work if you don't have a userform (see comments below).

For it to work with a UserForm, I changed the 'MatchEntry' to TRUE and also deleted any unwanted "change events" from my ComboBox code. The final code I use now is below:

```
Dim a()

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
  a = [Liste].Value
  Me.ComboBox1.List = a
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
  Set d1 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  tmp = UCase(Me.ComboBox1) & "*"
  For Each c In a
    If UCase(c) Like tmp Then d1(c) = ""
  Next c
  Me.ComboBox1.List = d1.keys
  Me.ComboBox1.DropDown
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  ActiveCell = Me.ComboBox1
  Unload Me
End Sub
Private Sub cmdClose_Click()
  Unload Me
End Sub
```

I thought I show it here in case anyone stumbles across my question.

Thank you!

Comment: @Tigeravatar's recommendation for data validation works if you don't have a UserForm (thank you again!). For it to work for me (with the UserForm), I followed his instructions about the `MatchRequired` and deleted the `Combobox_KeyDown` event from my code (see update above)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Select your cells where you want to put the data validation
- With the cells selected, go to Data Tab -> Validation
- Set "Allow" to "List" and set the Source to `=Liste` as shown here:

[image: Data Validation List screenshot]

- Next go to the "Error Alert" tab and set "Style" to "Warning" and enter the desired text in "Title" and "Error Message" as shown here:

[image: Data Validation Error Alert screenshot]

Test it out.  You should now have a drop-down list of valid choices, and if you attempt to manually enter an invalid choice you'll get the error message you specified.

As a note, if you want the data validation to completely disallow/prevent any entry not in the list, you'll need to set the Error Allert -> Style to be "Stop" instead of "Warning".

**EDIT**:

Per comments, it can't be a drop-down list.  I highly recommend using a drop-down list for this because it will be the most effective way to cut down on time entering data as well as reduce errors from typos.  However, if it absolutely cannot be a drop-down list, then you can use a Custom Data Validation and set the formula to `=ISNUMBER(MATCH(B7,Liste,0))` (we are using `B7` here because it is the first cell in the range of cells that contains this data validation).

[image: Data Validation Custom screenshot]

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work as I do not want the drop-down list to show up (which is why I have the userform instead). I would like it to just show the error allert instead. Any idea why it isn't working without the dropdown list?

Comment: @Veri Not sure why you wouldn't want the drop-down list as that will prevent errors because the user doesn't have to manually type, but if that absolutely cannot be a solution, then instead of a Data Validation `List`, use Data Validation `Custom` and then enter this formula: `=ISNUMBER(MATCH(B7,Liste,0))` (using `B7` because it's the first cell in the range that needs the data validation).

Comment: The reason I don't want the dropdown list is because I have the userform that pops up when clicking on the sell (where the user selects the item but which is also searchable in comparison to the dropdown list). I tried changing it to your new formula but it still doesn't work. It seems like it is because it doesn't recognize the userform input as a manual input (so it does not check it). I might try to go back to VBA and try it in the userform

Comment: @Veri That's correct, VBA input will overwrite/ignore data validation so no check occurs from there.  If the cell is being modified via VBA, then you will need to put a validation check in your code.

Comment: Do you have any recommendations on how to do this? (I have a code above that kind of works but for some reason the box doesn't pop up for all invalid entries but only some)? Or would it be better if I start a new post for that?

Comment: @Veri My first recommendation is always going to be to limit user input to only valid choices. So on the userform use a Combobox that is populated from your `Liste` range so that it only contains valid choices for the user to select from.  Now you can get rid of the `Worksheet_Change` event entirely.

Comment: I do have the combobox set up to have the dropdown with only items from the `Liste` (see above the full code) but it still lets you type in "Ad" and then hit enter (without selecting an item from the list). Is there anything I need to add in the combobox to prevent that? I can't change the Style setting to 2 "fmStyleDropdownList" because then my search function doesn't work anymore. I feel like I am going in circles

Comment: @Veri yes, comboboxes have a `MatchRequired` property.  It is `False` by default.  On the userform, select your combobox and change that property to `True`.  It will now give an error when an invalid entry is typed into the combobox and only accept a valid entry.

Comment: omg that worked! thank you! Is there any way I could force it to clear content if this error pops up or no?

Comment: @Veri You could technically use the Combobox's change event to check if it's ListIndex = -1 and if so set the ComboBox's text to `vbNullString` to simulate that effect, but in my opinion that's not really necessary. It already won't let you leave the combobox until a valid entry is selected.

Comment: It does let me leave the combobox. When I enter the the invalid input, it just shows me an error message and closes the userform. Do I also need to change my `MatchEntry`? At the moment it is set to `2 - fmMatchEntryNone`

Comment: @Veri if your userform is closing, that's a result of something in your userform code firing.  You'll need to open a new question if you're unable to locate that issue.  The new question will need your userform's code in order for us to assist.  The `MatchRequired` and `MatchEntry` properties by themselves are unable to close the userform regardless of what they're set to.

Comment: @Veri Hint, you probably have `Unload Me` somewhere in your userform code that is triggered by a change in your combobox

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I do have an `Unload Me` with a change in my combobox (when the down key is pressed to select an item). When I took that out, it works. I do have to hit enter twice for it to get selected but that's a small price to pay. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following formula:

=NOT(ISERROR(FIND("-"&A1&"-",(TEXTJOIN(,"-",TRUE,Sheet1!A1:A77)))))

That combines all the texts and then see if what's in the cell occurs in the list. I put it between dashes to prevent it from accepting partials.

Comment: It gives me an error saying "A named range you specified cannot be found". I am not sure why?